# yii2 plugins in dynamic-form wbraganca only work at first element

Tags: yii2

I'm using some plugins (yii\widgets\MaskedInput and kartik\select2\Select2) in wbraganca dynamic-form.
I notice these two plugins work only at first element.
Please advice. Thanks before.
my code like this

```
<?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]item_id")->widget(Select2::classname(), [
    'data' => ArrayHelper::map(Item::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),  
    'language' => 'en',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Select Items ...', 'onchange' => 'getItemPrice($(this))'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true
    ],
]) ?>

<?= $form->field($detail, "[{$i}]qty")->widget(\yii\widgets\MaskedInput::className(),
[
    'clientOptions' => [
    'alias' => 'numeric',
    'groupSeparator' => ',',
    'digits' => 0,
    'autoGroup' => true,
    'removeMaskOnSubmit' => true,
    'rightAlign' => false,                                  
    ],
    'options' => [
       'class' => 'form-control',
       'onchange' => 'calculateSubtotal($(this))',                                  
    ]                               
]) ?>
```

Comment: I think your question is duplicated with this http://stackoverflow.com/a/42931746/3787302

Comment: it is different. it only ask how to iterate.  but my question is after add another row, the plugins don't work anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found my answer for this question. It is actually answered in github.com/wbraganca.
Here what i do:
1. for kartik/select2, modify source code *yii2-dynamic-form.js* (remember to delete web/assets files to make it effect)

```
// "kartik-v/yii2-widget-select2"
   var $hasSelect2 = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-krajee-select2]');
   if ($hasSelect2.length > 0) {
      $hasSelect2.each(function() {
          var id = $(this).attr('id');
          var configSelect2 = eval($(this).attr('data-krajee-select2'));

                // $(this).select2('destroy');
                if ($(this).data('select2')) {
                    $(this).select2('destroy');
                }

                var configDepdrop = $(this).data('depdrop');
                if (configDepdrop) {
                    configDepdrop = $.extend(true, {}, configDepdrop);
                    $(this).removeData().off();
                    $(this).unbind();
                    _restoreKrajeeDepdrop($(this));
                }
                var s2LoadingFunc = typeof initSelect2Loading != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                var s2OpenFunc = typeof initSelect2DropStyle != 'undefined' ? initSelect2Loading : initS2Loading;
                $.when($('#' + id).select2(configSelect2)).done(s2LoadingFunc(id, '.select2-container--krajee'));

                var kvClose = 'kv_close_' + id.replace(/\-/g, '_');

                $('#' + id).on('select2:opening', function(ev) {
                    s2OpenFunc(id, kvClose, ev);
                });

                $('#' + id).on('select2:unselect', function() {
                    window[kvClose] = true;
                });

                if (configDepdrop) {
                    var loadingText = (configDepdrop.loadingText) ? configDepdrop.loadingText : 'Loading ...';
                    initDepdropS2(id, loadingText);
                }                
            });
        }
```

2. for yii/widgets/MaskedInput, also change *yii2-dynamic-form.js* (add some code) :
   `var _restoreSpecialJs = function(widgetOptions) {
       var widgetOptionsRoot = _getWidgetOptionsRoot(widgetOptions);
       // "jquery.inputmask"
       var $hasInputmask = $(widgetOptionsRoot.widgetItem).find('[data-plugin-inputmask]');
       if ($hasInputmask.length > 0) {
           $hasInputmask.each(function() {
               $(this).inputmask('remove');
               $(this).inputmask(eval($(this).attr('data-plugin-inputmask')));
           });
       }`

and then Copy MaskedInput.php to your folder project (mine : models\MaskedInput.php) and change this code

```
$view->registerJs("var {$this->_hashVar} = {$encOptions};", View::POS_READY);
```

to

```
$view->registerJs("var {$this->_hashVar} = {$encOptions};", View::POS_END);
```

remember to use MaskedInput from your edited file.
Thanks it.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you want reinitialize the widgets when you add new element(form).See below link this not exactly you want, but same as your case.

[wbraganca yii2 dynamic form date picker issue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40651844/wbraganca-yii2-dynamic-form-date-picker-issue)

Comment: still don't understand how to add the element. when click add new row, in console i got error : Uncaught ReferenceError: initSelect2Loading is not defined

Comment: maybe i should change the topic how to reinit Select2 kartik in dynamic-form?

Answer (score 0):

composer require pceuropa/yii2-forms dev-master

Answer (score 0):

After read some issues in wbraganca github, i've decided to use this fork from that repo.

```
https://github.com/vivekmarakana/yii2-dynamicform
```

But in some case, that fork still buggy for me in `widgetOptions` array. Fix them manually, by removing that index (`[i]`) in error line.